Pull amazon-k8s-cni policy from aws public ecr gallery
I have a usecase where I want to pull a public amazon-k8s-cni image from AWS public ecr mentioned in this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-ons-images.html all of these repositories are public aws ecr and managed by aws
I want to use an iam role which has the required permission and can be assume by Go code

You need to attach this policy AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly to your
role, it's a managed policy.
And add the service runing your Go code in trusted identities for your role, for example if you are runing your code in EC2 add EC2 in trusted identities for your role and attach your role to the instance choose Actions > Security > Modify IAM Role.
hope this help.
